# How to query from sqlite3 database if content in the entry match small requirement

Tags: python, string, tkinter, sqlite

I want to querying data from `sqlite3` db from python and populate it in a `Listbox` but if am doing the search i have to provide the full name like `Harvard University` before the records can be inserted into the `Listbox`.

I want to query record like `Harvard University` by providing only `Harvard` then it will output all `records` with `Havard` content in it for me because if i don't provide full name it will not populate the `listbox` with any record.

Your suggestions are welcome to achieve this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("STATS.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS institution(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
name TEXT)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()


def query_record():
    data1 = e1_search.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("STATS.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM institution WHERE name=?", (data1,))
    row = cur.fetchall()

    for n in row:
        List.insert(tk.END, n)
        print(n)
    conn.close()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

List = tk.Listbox(root, width=100)
List.pack()

e1_search = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e1_search)
e1.pack()

b = tk.Button(text="Search", command=query_record)
b.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may want to see `startswith` method on string objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have to modify the query.
Since `"SELECT * FROM institution WHERE name=?", (data1,)` 
will exactly match the input string you can try with,

`"SELECT * FROM institution WHERE name like ?", (data1+'%',)`.

Hope this works!

Comment: Daaniyaa is it possible that it can be made to search from middle like `Havard University` then i searched by `University` rather than havard

Comment: i found out when search by `university` the records doesn't appear because it not at the start

Comment: For Harvard University to appear when you type University you can modify the query to - ('%' + data1 + '%').